# optapy_error: [Errno 2] JVM DLL not found: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib

Tags: python, java, optaplanner, optapy

Could you help me fix this error: [image]

I've tried to run the example from https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/optapy-optapy-quickstarts-qdcpkydn/notebooks/school-timetabling/school-timetabling-quickstart.ipynb

I've installed jdk-21, and python 3.9 and set the `JAVA_HOME` env = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home'

Also I've checked that the file `libjli.dylib` from error is inside the path [image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)